# Debugging 10.6 on Xcode 4.4

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, debugging, gdb

I've been recently trying to compile a static library for a game engine in Xcode. I'm using OS X 10.8 and Xcode 4.4. I managed to copy the 10.6 platform from an old installation of Xcode. After a bit of copying stuff, I managed to get a runnable 10.6 SDK with appropriate headers and stuff. I had to use GDB for debugging, as LLDB doesn't like 10.6 any more. Debugging went OK for a bit, until I touched one build setting, no clue which. Doing a snapshot restore fixed nothing. Anyway, now debugging is really shakey. What will happen is this: The first time I run the application, everything works normally. It launches the game, loads the static library, breakpoints work, everything is fine. But after that, the next attempt at running, and all future attempts result in this error message:

```
Unable to find Mach task port for process-id 49069: (os/kern) failure (0x5).
```

A crash report reports this:

```
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   dyld                            0x8fe01030 _dyld_start + 0
```

The debugger output shows no information other than what's normal.

Is there a way to get Xcode 4.4 to compile for 10.6 and run 100% of the time?

Edit: I tried using the technique described at http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/BuildingOnDarwin but the error still remains.

Comment: Found your error [here](http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/BuildingOnDarwin)

Comment: @CodaFi did that and it still doesn't work.